# How to obviate the problem of no spaces when joining lines in ed

Tags: ed

In ed it is easy to join lines together. For example,

`12,13j` joins lines 12 and 13

`-1,.j` joins the line before to the current line

However, ed does not add a space between the joined lines,
and therefore one is often left with this situation:

```
Line 1
Line 2 
>Line1Line2
```

One could first add a space and then join the lines, as in,

```
1g/$/s// /\
1,2j
```

but this is somewhat cumbersome.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to join the next line to the current line, I would proably use the two separate commands

```
s/$/ /
j
```

(The default address for `j` is `.,.+1`)

Add an address to the `s` command if you want to reposition the current line first.

The `g` command is only really needed here if you want to be able to undo *both* edits with `u`:

```
.g/$/ s// /\
j
```

or, if you want to use some more elaborate criteria for what lines to join with the next line,

```
g/RE/ s/$/ /\
j
```